# Phoca Gallery -> Slideshow shows filenames instead of category (Joomla 3.x)

Tags: joomla, slideshow, photo-gallery, shadowbox

I have a small problem with Phoca Gallery (latest v4.3.10) under Joomla 3.8.12

On my old site, when i clicked on a (sub)category, the slideshow (setting ShadowBox) would start. On each of the images, the CATEGORY name woul dbe displayed above each image.

Now, I am building the site anew, but now the filename is shown for each image instea dof the category

I have been searching and searching on the internet, but I can't find anything on how to change that to showing the category name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just silly,

After posting this question I discovered how to fix this in 5 minutes.....

It is not the filename being shown, but the TITLE of the image uploaded to Phoca Gallery. So, if I change the titles all to the category name, and have different aliases, it works as desired.....

Still, this reeks of cumbersome, and there still might be a better way?